# Compound index and querying by one component of it

Tags: mongodb, indexing

```
db.collection("mycollection").createIndex(
        {
            prop1:   "text",
            prop2:   -1
        },
        {
            name:   "someindex1",

            partialFilterExpression: {
                prop2: false
            }
        }
);
```

We have that index created.

`prop1` is `string`, `prop2` is `boolean`. What I'd like to ask is:

1. Does MongoDB will use this index when I will search, by querying only by `prop1`? Or I need to create separated index only for `prop1`?
2. For `prop1` there will be only few static values, like in `enum` data type, but in future there could be more possible values added to it. Does `text` type of index is a good choice? I don't need features like in-text search or something, it's more like `enum`

Comment: 1. Yes, it will: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index. 2. what's the point to have an index for a field with such low selectivity? what is "in-text" search that you don't need?  Try to rephrase your question with what you need from an index instead. Indexes are expensive, especially the text ones.

Comment: @AlexBlex I need to index some data by theirs owner ID (microservice process). There are currently 6 processes running, each of them process data and store it to mongodb, after restarting any of them, process should load from mongo only data that was created by that process (by owner ID which is always the same string value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not.

The index was build with a partial filter, so it will only contain keys for documents where `prop2` is false, so this index will only return correct results when the query also filters on `prop2:false`.

For example, if the collection contains 2 documents:

```
{ prop1: "value1", prop2: true },
{ prop1: "value1", prop2: false}
```

The index will contain a single key: `{"":"value1", "":false}` pointing to the second document.

If you query for `{$text:{$search:"value1"}, prop2: false}` the query executor can use the index to find the single matching document.

However, if you query for `{$text:{$search:"value1"}}` it should return both documents.  Since the index only contains a key for the second document, if the query executor used the index, its results would be incorrect.